# EF 4.1 Codefirst WPF Eager Loading Data Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, eager-loading

I am having problems databinding to EF code first.  I need to be using Eager Loading, but I am running into some issues with databinding.  I have the following classes:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    DbSet<A> As;
    DbSet<B> Bs;
    DbSet<C> Cs;
}
public class A
{
   public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
   public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am data binding Context.As to a Treeview, using the below code:

```
Context.As.Load();
tvItems.ItemsSource = Context.As.Local;
```

This works as expected, however, it does not automatically load the child properties, Bs, and subsequently, Cs.  So, I found that lazy loading can help with this, like so:

```
Context.As.Load();
tvItems.ItemsSource = Context.As.Include(u=>u.Bs);
```

From my reading, this should automatically load at least the first level of child properties.  However, this will not data bind, as I did not use .Local

.Include() returns IQueryable, which does not support .Local.  I can use .ToList(), but this will not automatically update when I add items.

So, how the hell am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Context.As.Include(a => a.Bs).Load();
tvItems.ItemsSource = Context.As.Local;
```

Comment: Should have figured that out on my own... Thanks a lot!